# How to handle data - Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8.1

I have looked what seems everywhere for this but maybe it is too obvious and no one mentions it but I am making a windows 8 app and I want the user to be able to edit the data.

Lets say im trying to make a To-Do list, I want the user to be able to add entries. For my current app with dummy static data I have these entries stored in an array in a javascript file. Should I just make the user be able to add/edit/remove entries in the array or is there a different method I should use?

If someone could link me some material to read or an example that shows what I am looking for it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the JavaScript framework you're using. Assuming that you're using Microsoft's own WinJS, what you're looking for is "data binding". This allows you to bind an object or an array to a "control" and have it be automatically updated. Then you just work with the array, adding, removing, sorting items. The data-bind automatically reflects those changes in the template.

Here is a quick example of data-binding from MSDNs own documentation:

```
<div id="listDiv"  
    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
    data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : dataList.dataSource }">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dataArray = [
        { name: "Marley", species: "dog" },
        { name: "Lola", species: "cat" },
        { name: "Leo", species: "dog" },
        { name: "Izzy", species: "cat" },
        { name: "Ziggy", species: "cat" },
        { name: "Ruby", species: "dog" }
    ];

    var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);
    WinJS.UI.processAll();
</script>
```

You can see more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx

Each JavaScript framework does this a little bit differently. For example, AngularJS would let you bind an array to a list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Where 'list' is the name of an array of objects in your scope, item is a single object in the array, and item.name is a string with the name of a single object. The syntax is different, but once again, you would simply manipulate the array and it would be reflected in the resulting HTML.

Comment: I started the app with the Grid App template provided by Microsoft so I am using the WinJS framework

Comment: how can I add items to the array. Do i need to store the array in Local Storage?

Comment: You would add/remove items from the array using normal JavaScript array methods like dataArray.push(newObject) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array.  You could (and probably should) store data, WinJS offers a number of methods for accomplishing this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781225.aspx. For a small todo list, I'd probably recommend sessionState.